# CheckedListBox items to SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to perform a SQL Select query based on the user input from a Checked List Box.  I was able to find some code, but the solution doesn't seem to be working.  On the debug, it keeps crapping out on line 3 and I have no idea why.

Any help would be grateful.

```
Dim DistrictString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    For h = 0 To Me.District.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        If Me.District.CheckedItems(h).Selected Then
            DistrictString.Append(Me.District.CheckedItems(h).Value & ",")
        End If
    Next
```

With some of the advice, here is the newly edited version of the code, it is now crashing on the Append line.

The new error is 'Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found'

```
Dim DistrictW As String
Dim DistrictX As String
Dim DistrictString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    For h = 0 To Me.District.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        DistrictString.Append(Me.District.CheckedItems(h).Value & ",")
    Next
DistrictW = DistrictString.ToString
DistrictX = DistrictW.Substring(0, DistrictString.Length - 1)
```

Comment: "Crapping Out" is not an error message in VB.Net.

Comment: What does "crap out" mean?

Comment: I am debugging an add-in for ESRI's ArcMap, and the application is crashing on this line.  On the crash, it doesn't provide an error.  Looks like the error is "Public member "Selected" on type "String" not found.

Comment: What is the type of the objects in your `CheckedListBox` (and thus in the `CheckedItems` collection)?

Comment: The way this reads, you have two layers, the first is the 'checked items', and the second is the highlighted item, which may or may not be checked.  What you are probably trying to do is simply iterate through all checked items.  You don't need the If / End If construction at all, but you do need the .Append line.  Also, after the next you'll need to lop off the last comma.

Comment: @MeredithPoor Or you could use the `OfType` function, `Select` (to get the values) and `String.Join`. Something like `String.Join(",", Me.District.CheckedItems.OfType(Of MyObject)().Select(Function(o) o.Value))` where MyObject is the type of the objects in the CheckedListBox. Obviously for readability you can write the code on multiple lines.

Comment: The boxes are simply integers, 1-7

Comment: The program is telling me the error: Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found

Comment: Change ".Value" to ".ToString()"  and it should work.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks so much!  That solved the problem.  I'd give you a hug if I could!

Comment: @BrianJBaldwin Uhhm, virtual is just fine.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped, this is the solution that I implemented

Learned a lot from this little exercise.

```
Dim DistrictW As String
Dim DistrictX As String
Dim DistrictString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    For h = 0 To Me.District.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        DistrictString.Append(Me.District.CheckedItems(h).ToString & ",")
    Next
DistrictW = DistrictString.ToString
DistrictX = DistrictW.Substring(0, DistrictString.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Me.District.CheckedItems.Items(h).Selected Then

     DistrictString.Append(Me.District.CheckedItems.Items(h).Value & ",")

End If
```

Use CheckboxList.Items

Comment: 'Items' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection'.

Comment: Sorry thought you were using ASP.net with "CheckedItems" being the name of the CheckboxList control.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you are creating a expression like `...xyz in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')...` the following code might be more appropriate:

> For h = 0 To Me.District.CheckedItems.Count - 1
>
> ```
>        DistrictString += "'" & Me.District.CheckedItems(h).Value & "',"
> ```
>
> Next
>
> DistrictString = DistrictString.Substring(0, DistrictString.Length - 1)

There is no point in messing with the .SELECTED property at all. Everything that's checked is 'selected' for your purposes.

Comment: Dim DistrictString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        For h = 0 To Me.District.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            DistrictString.Append(Me.District.CheckedItems(h).Value & ",")
        End If
        Next
        DistrictString = DistrictString.Substring(0, DistrictString.Length - 1)

</br>
This is giving me two errors now, 1) 'End If' must be preceded by a matching 'if' and 2) 'Substring' is not a member of 'system.text.substring'

Comment: I feel like I'm getting too complicated with this, but here is what I have thus far and the crash is now occurring where the Append takes place.
    `Dim DistrictW As String
        Dim DistrictX As String
        Dim DistrictString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        For h = 0 To Me.District.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            DistrictString.Append(Me.District.CheckedItems(h).Value & ",")
        Next
        DistrictW = DistrictString.ToString
        DistrictX = DistrictW.Substring(0, DistrictString.Length - 1)`